# Where do I define the behaviour of a closure when trying to communicate between 2 VCs?

Tags: swift, closures

I have 2 separate view controllers, and am using a closure to communicate between them. I want a button pressed on VC one to change the background color of VC two.
However, pressing the button with the following code does nothing:

```
class VCOne: UIViewController {

    var delta: () -> Void = { }

    @objc func buttonPressed() {
       delta()
     }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super. viewDidLoad()

    let pageController = PageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal)
            addChild(pageController)
            pageController.didMove(toParent: self)
           pageContainerView.addSubview(pageController.view)



}


class VCTwo: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    VCOne().delta = {
       view.backgroundColor = .red
          }
     }
}
```

Now, I believe my error is that I'm making a new instance of VCOne when I initialise it again in viewDidLoad() of VCTwo(), but I cannot access delta() in VCTwo() any other way.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: How do you navigate from VCOne to VCTwo?

Comment: @ParagBafna VcTwo is actually embedded in a PageViewController, which takes up the bottom half of VCOne. So basically, its VCOne as the main VC, with the lower half of the screen being a swipe-able PageViewController

Comment: @ParagBafna edited the question

Comment: “Now, I believe my error is that I'm making a new instance of VCOne” You are right, that’s the error. See http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Answer (score 0):

A most common approach is to create delegate property in your second view controller.

```
class VCTwo: UIViewController {

  weak var delegate: VCOne!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white

    delegate.delta = {
       view.backgroundColor = .red
          }
     }
}
```

Set delegate value to VCOne after init VCTwo

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say you want to pass string from VC2 to VC1 using closure, then you can follow below steps-

1. declare closure variable in VC2 as,

   ```
   var completionBlock: ((String) -> Void)?
   ```
2. While going back from VC2->VC1 ,
   In VC2 pass the value from completionBlock.

   ```
   let stringToPass = "xyz"
   VC2.completionBlock = { stringToPass in
      if self.completionBlock != nil {
        self.completionBlock!(stringToPass)
      }
   }
   ```
3. While pushing VC2 from VC1, set

   ```
   VC2.completionBlock = { strGotFromVC2 in
     self.requiredValueFromVC2 = strGotFromVC2
   }
   ```

In this way u can get value in requiredValueFromVC2 variable of VC1, passed from VC2 using Closure